# Server provisioning without PXE

Tags: puppet, provisioning, foreman

I have a lot of servers in different data centers which should be reinstalled from time to time.

I am familiar with **Puppet** so I am able to configure the O/S after it boots up but I can't perform an automated reinstall.

All the tools for bare metal provisioning like **Foreman** or **Razor** use advantages of **iPXE** booting to run a micro distro and pull all necessary *kickstart* or *preseed* files from a master server and so on. But for me it's impossible because I can't organize servers into a network with my own DHCP and **iPXE**, etc.

But almost all data centers I am working with have a livecd/rescue mode function.

So I thought maybe there is an automated bare metal provisioning tool which can be used if I have an SSH access to the LiveCD? It can either simply SSH into system and directly run commands, or setup a local iPXE server, start QEMU, install O/S then reboot and run Puppet for further configuration process.

So does it exist?

PS. At the end of composing this answer I thought that maybe I can just solve the PXE problem using a bash script which installs **GRUB2** over SSH to LieveCD which then will download all things needed for **Razor**/**Foreman** over HTTP?

Comment: If you can load your own kernel it's possible to install CentOS from GRUB. http://serverfault.com/a/634796/9517

Comment: Which OS/flavor/distribution are you trying to install?

Comment: CentOS or Debian.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Foreman](http://theforeman.org) and the [foreman_bootdisk](https://github.com/theforeman/foreman_bootdisk) plugin.

You should set up Foreman, add your hosts, and boot them using the foreman_bootdisk generated image, a hybrid ISO. In that case you don't need DHCP and iPXE for anything (in fact the plugin is meant for that exact use case).

The README of the foreman_bootdisk contains more documentation about how does it work, and it can be installed through the Foreman installer or as a package (deb and RPM)

Comment: How do I boot from a `foreman_bootdisk` if for example I do not have control over the bios, boot options, etc?