# How to get location of anaconda-ks.cfg script from within itself?

Tags: kickstart

I'm installing CentOS 7 using the `ks` option. Example:

```
ks=http://10.0.0.100:8080/anaconda-ks.cfg
```

From within this configuration file, how can I "dynamically" fetch the URL of its location?

In this case, I want this: `"http://10.0.0.100:8080/"`

EDIT: Ultimately, what am doing is I match the MAC address of the machine against a Python dictionary (JSON file) in order to determine which hostname to set during installation. And I would like to avoid hard-coding the URL to the JSON file into the kickstart configuration script.

Comment: Why do you need it ?

Comment: I wish to open up a .json file residing (on the same URL) from inside the configuration script, using `%pre --interpreter=/usr/bin/python`

Comment: You could probably do something hacky with netstat to figure it out, not recommended. I'm not aware of a clean way to determine this with a ks option.

Comment: Again, you should think about dynamically generating kickstarts server-side. It'll be much, much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that is exposed to the kickstart script that is useful is the kernel command line. You can access this at

```
/proc/cmdline
```

If you're using the solution I [provided here](https://serverfault.com/questions/745515/how-to-remotely-initiate-netinstall-of-centos-7/745526#745526)  then you can read the `ks=...` parameter. You can pass /proc/cmdline to a pipe, something like

```
url=`sed 's/=/ /g' /proc/cmdline | awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i~/ks/) print $(i+1)}'`
```

would return the field following `ks` to `url` once we have converted the `=` to spaces.

I don't have access to a kickstart environment not to test this so uyou may need to tweek it a bit with paths.

Comment: I just realised that this returns the full file path. It should be pretty easy to modify it to remove the last bit.

Comment: Excellent, I used Python's `subprocess.check_output( ['cat', '/proc/cmdline'] )` and then detected the URL from the returned string.

Comment: That looks like an embedded [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) to me. Python can surely just read the file itself without the need to spawn a subprocess.

Comment: Oh, that is completely right. This should work: `with open('/proc/cmdline', 'r') as myfile: data = myfile.read()` - thanks for pointing that out. Not sure why I took the detour of subprocessing... (late night coding I guess)

Answer (score 0):

You can send hostname parameter as kernel parameters (--extra-args in virt-install call). For example:

```
# virt-install \
    -n centos   \
    -r 2048   \
    --vcpus=1   \
    --os-variant=rhel7 \
    -accelerate \
    -w bridge:virbr0   \
    --disk path=/opt/vm/test2.qcow2,size=100 \
    -l /opt/iso/CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-DVD.iso \
    --name test2 \
    --extra-args "ks=http://192.168.122.1/ks.cfg ksdevice=eth0 ip=192.168.122.40 netmask=255.255.255.0 dns=8.8.8.8 gateway=192.168.122.1 hostname=my-hostname"
```

And hostname automatically will be configure as my-hostname.

Comment: This is on physical hardware http://serverfault.com/questions/745515/how-to-remotely-initiate-netinstall-of-centos-7.